# What are some good food options for a one year-old?

Tags: infant, weight, babyfood

My child is about 12 months old. He has been weaned from breastfeeding. As of right now, his weight is normal, but he will need to gain more weight eventually. Can I feed him milk, Boost or Horlicks? I will be consulting a pediatrician, but he keeps saying the weight is normal. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you believe your paediatrician?

Comment: Because they give all medicine,its always not good for children, need so health natural foods .so I believe pediatrician will give all medicine always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small steamed foods. Soft solids should be okay too. Nothing seasoned. Make sure the pieces are small enough to swallow whole since chewing is new if you haven't been doing solids foods before now. Small bits and keep it simple. Focus on fruits and veggies. My son would only eat fruits veggies rice and chicken for like for months.

Pureed foods are still okay, but we started those around six months. If you're just starting out introducing foods just keep it very simple and only try one new thing every few days to make sure there's no allergy.

For teething, frozen peas are amazing and it teaches them to like veggies.